# How do I set up grunt in WEB IDE for an older SAP UI5 project?

Tags: sapui5, sap-web-ide

We have a few older SAPUI5 projects developed outside of SAP WEB IDE

(E.g. Deployed through Eclipse using ABAP/SAPUI5 Plugins).

As we moved onto developing all new projects in SAP WEB IDE, we thought it would be a good idea to move our old projects into WEB IDE and deploy everything from here.

Part of this would be using the existing Grunt setup in WEB IDE as opposed to gulp which was set up on the older project.

We imported an existing (older) project from our Git repo and followed the setup instruction here:

https://help.sap.com/viewer/825270ffffe74d9f988a0f0066ad59f0/CF/en-US/47045080ddaf414ba520d77353fc9441.html

However, we get ui5-preload errors. The dist folder is created and but no files are written to it.

We've followed the troubleshooting guides to no avail.

The project still works but without any build to improve performance.

As a stop-gap, we're manually running the older gulp script locally, but would much prefer to run grunt and everything under Web-IDE.

Any Ideas?

....

On closer inspection I added the "vscode-uri": "1.0.6" to package.json.

https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/0002801814.

This now runs the build without error.

However - The component-preload.js files are exactly the same, and when the project is deployed. we get a File sap/zp2pui/index.html NOT found! error.

Comment: `we get ui5-preload errors` which ones?

Comment: `The project still works but with any build to improve performance` this sentence is totally unclear. what means "with any build"? Need more input info

Comment: Edits made to the original Question. full error logs to follow....

Comment: I've now got the build process to complete. But this has caused further problems when deployed to our ECC system  - index.html not found.  See original post for updates.

Comment: so it completed but not correctly. have you tried creating a new webide development and replacing the content of the webapp folder and see if you can make that work?

Comment: Thanks @jorg. I don't think it's worth the risk as the change would be too big in ECC. It's an existing live app.